# For what values of $x$ is it possible to compute $\cos(x \phi)$ with vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

When we have two vectors $a = (a_{1}, a_{2}, \dots, a_{n})$ and $b = (b_{1}, b_{2}, \dots, b_{n})$ of the same length, we can compute the cosine of the angle between them by means of the following formula: $$\cos(\phi_{ab}) = \frac{\langle a, b \rangle}{||a|| \cdot ||b||} \quad .$$

I was wondering whether we can use this definition to compute $\cos(x \cdot \phi_{ab})$ for some number $x$. In particular, I am interested in computing this when $x=2$, but I'm also curious about general $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: There is a unique $\phi_{ab} \in [0,\pi]$ such that $\cos(\phi_{ab}) = \langle a,b\rangle / \|a\|/\|b\|$. With this $\phi_{ab}$ you can compute $\cos(x \, \phi_{ab})$ for arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Or do you have something different in mind?

Comment: @gerw I understand one can compute $\phi_{ab} =  \cos^{-1}  ( \frac{ \langle a, b \rangle }{ ||a|| \cdot ||b|| } )$, and derive $cos(x \phi_{ab})$ from there, but I was wondering whether there we somewhat neater formulas for, for example, $\cos(2 \phi_{ab})$ which can be computed "instantly" with the vectors $a$ and $b$ and some operations from linear algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find $k$ such that $\|kb-a\|=\|a\|$. Then $2\phi_{ab}=\phi_{a,kb-a}$, so you can do your calculation.

To find $k$, we have $(kb-a)\cdot(kb-a)=a\cdot a$, so $b\cdot bk^2-2a\cdot bk=0$, so, ignoring $k=0$, we get $k=2(a\cdot b)/(b\cdot b)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a question about the first two sentences though. Why is it true that $2 \phi_{ab} = \phi_{a, kb-a}$ when $||kb-a|| = ||a|| $ ?

Comment: @MaxMuller $kb-a$ is the reflection of $a$ about the line $tb$.